# Conditionally copying script from system to install directory

Tags: autoconf, automake

I have a script in the system that I might want to install into my install directory, however I only want to do this in release mode. So I have a configure flag `--enable-release` to control this:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE(release,
              AC_HELP_STRING([--enable-release],
                             [enable release build, default: no]),
              [case "${enableval}" in
                     yes) release=yes ;;
                     no) release=no ;;
                     *) AC_MSG_ERROR([bad value ${enableval} for --enable-release]) ;;
               esac],
              [release=no])
if test "x$release" != xno; then
    AC_DEFINE([PRODUCT_RELEASE], [1],
              [Define if we are preparing a release build.])
fi
AM_CONDITIONAL([RELEASE], [test "x$release != xno"])
```

Then I have another configure flag so that the user can instruct configure with the path to the script:

```
AC_ARG_WITH(script-path,
  AS_HELP_STRING(--with-script-path,[Path of script binaries]),
  AC_SUBST(SCRIPTPATH,[$withval]))
AC_PATH_PROG([SMTSCRIPT], [cvc4], [no], [$SCRIPTPATH:$PATH])

if test "x$ac_cv_path_SMTSCRIPT" != xno; then
   AC_DEFINE([HAVE_SCRIPT], [1],
                           [Define if we could find SMT script in path.])
   if test "x$release" != xno; then
      SMTSCRIPT_CPPFLAGS="-DSOLVERBIN=\"\\\"$ac_cv_path_SMTSCRIPT\\\"\""
   else
      SMTSCRIPT_CPPFLAGS="-DSCRIPTBIN=\"\\\"$bindir/cvc4\\\"\""
   fi
   AC_SUBST([SMTSCRIPT_CPPFLAGS])
fi
```

In Makefile.am I tried:

```
dist_bin_SCRIPTS = $(top_srcdir)/scripts/asmWrapper.py $(top_srcdir)/scripts/live_bar.py
if RELEASE
    dist_bin_SCRIPTS += $(SCRIPTPATH)/cvc4
endif
```

Unfortunately automake seems to ignore my if and `dist_bin_SCRIPT` never gets appended with the path to cvc4.

Comment: Offhand it looks reasonable, though I don't think you want "dist_" for a script that apparently isn't part of your project.  I would start by looking in the Makefile to see how RELEASE is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem it turns out is the tab on the conditional appending to `dist_bin_SCRIPTS`. This works:

```
dist_bin_SCRIPTS = $(top_srcdir)/scripts/asmWrapper.py $(top_srcdir)/scripts/live_bar.py
if RELEASE
dist_bin_SCRIPTS += $(SCRIPTPATH)/cvc4
endif
```